# ECS : find the size of an entity since creation & reduce redundant code

Tags: c++, memory-management, entity, c++14, game-engine

I am trying to optimize an entity-component-system game engine (ECS).

### Version A

Currently, a ship entity is create via 3 steps.

- `SystemShip` requests `ECS` to create new blank entity
- `SystemShip` requests `ECS` to attach `ComShip`
- `SystemShip` requests `SystemHP` to attach **any component(s)** `SystemHP` **wants** to make a certain entity has HP-feature.

Here is the memory lay-out for 1 entity.
(I know there are several ways, but I decide to choose this layout.)

[image]

It works OK, here is the stub (runable) :-

```
class Entity{};
class ECS{
    public: static Entity createEntity(){
        return Entity();
    }
    public: template<class C> static void attach(Entity e){
        //some logic that extend memory used for "e" 
        //   also placement new (...) C();
        return;
    }
};
class ComHP{};
class SystemHP{
    public: static void addHPFeature(Entity e){
        ECS::attach<ComHP>(e);
        // set some value to the ComHP instance
        return;
    }
};
class ComShip{};
class SystemShip{
    public: static Entity createShip(){
        Entity entity=ECS::createEntity();
        ECS::attach<ComShip>(entity);
        SystemHP::addHPFeature(entity);
        return entity;
    }
};
int main(){
    Entity e=SystemShip::createShip();
}
```

### Version B

I found later that the above approaches is not quite friendly for memory management.

It is much better and easily to optimize if ECS know every type components it need at the time entity create, and even better if I know it **at the beginning of program** (i.e. using template).

With the below solution, it can reserve a correct size of memory. (marked at `##HAPPY##`)
Here is a stub of design :-

```
class Entity{};
class ECS{
    public: template<class ...C> static Entity createEntity2(){
        //##HAPPY##
        //some logic that extend memory used for "e" 
        //   also placement new (...) ComShip() and ComHP();
        return Entity();
    }
};
class ComHP{};
class SystemHP{
    public: static void addHPFeature(Entity e){
        // set some value to the ComHP instance
        return;
    }
};
class ComShip{};
class SystemShip{
    public: static Entity createShip(){
        Entity entity=ECS::createEntity2<ComShip,ComHP>();
        SystemHP::addHPFeature(entity);
        return entity;
    }
};
int main(){
    Entity e=SystemShip::createShip();
}
```

## Problem

Although it works, there are 3 disadvantages of the version B :-

### **1st**

Now, `SystemShip` has to recognize what type of component(s) that `SystemHP` want.

It is somehow break encapsulation, and it is quite harder to maintain.

If `SystemHP` would need more components to implement the `HP` feature, I will need to refactor `SystemShip` and other places that call `SystemHP::addHPFeature()`.

### **2nd**

The code of version B is *somehow* duplicated :-

```
 1. Entity entity=ECS::createEntity2<ComShip,ComHP>(); //ComHP <-- forget
 2. SystemHP::addHPFeature(entity);                    //HP again
```

Comparing the version A :-

```
 SystemHP::addHPFeature(entity);                       //one line
```

It is a little error-prone : I may forget to add `ComHP` when create entity.

### **3rd**

`SystemShip` requires full definition of `ComHP`.
It can be alleviated by using std::function or its family, but suffer cost of function pointer (or v table).

## Question

How to alleviate disadvantages of version B?

**Edit:**
I feel that a partial solution is to let `SystemHP` has a pack type-def.
It may be `SystemHP::allTypesRequired` that I can use it like `createEntity3<ComShip,SystemHP::type_allTypesRequired>()`.
I have to find a way to zip it and unzip it back to list of component types (`{ComHP}`).

Comment: In general `public:` or `private:` is not placed before every member in C++. It is not like C# or Java ....

Comment: @knivil Sorry for my bad habit.  I will try to improve myself, thank.